# Is a homomorphic function under addition even on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a function with the property

$$f(x +y) = f(x) +f(y)$$

Now

$$f(-y) = f(-2y + y) = f(-2y) + f(y) \tag{1}$$ 
  $$ f(y) = f(2y + (-y)) = f(2y)  + f(-y)  \tag{2} $$

Substituting (2) into (1)

$$f(-y) = f(-2y) + f(2y)  + f(-y)$$

$$ f(2y) = f(-2y)$$

--

### Edit: the last line should read $-f(2y) = f(-2y)$ if I would have done my arithmetic correctly.

Comment: Try $f(x)=x$ and see where your mistake is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In fact the function is odd, so it's not even unless it is 0.

Note that
$$f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)$$
Hence $f(0)=0$. Now
$$0=f(0)=f(y+(-y))=f(y)+f(-y)$$
Hence
$$f(y)=-f(-y)$$

Comment: What about $f(-2) = f(-4 + 2) = f(-4) + f(2) = f(-4) + f(4 -2) = f(-4) + f(4) + f(-2) \implies f(-4) = -f(4)$  ... oh